# loading from csv to Snowflake staging: all the records going to a single field

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i am loading the data from csv file to snowflake staging table, but the records are not going to all the fields instead the data is going to single field.
i am using necessary options while creating file format.
type = csv

```
   field_delimiter = ','

   skip_header = 1

   field_optionally_enclosed_by = '"'
```

please suggest if any option that i am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide some example data with the structure of your csv file and your full copy command?

Comment: You should likely confirm that your file is actually delimited by a comma.  Doesn't sound like it is.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i am able to resolve it. the issue was with the file format , i have created file format individually instead of creating it within stage creation, when i create fileformat within the stage creation then that was working. Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user says the issue has been resolved (in the comments)